# Retriggering a GET request React under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am using jquery to make a `GET` [request to a quiz API](http://jservice.io/). I am using React to show the question to the user, and if they get the question correct I want to trigger the API request and fetch a new question.

I have tried to trigger the function that makes the `GET` request if the user gets the correct answer, however the console tells me `this.serverRequest is not a function`

I have only started learning react yesterday so forgive any awful errors, but also feel free to provide feedback on how the code could be improved.

Please see code below which should hopefully provide more clarity on the issue I am facing.

```
var Quiz = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            question: '',
            answer: '',
            score: 0
        }
  },

  checkAnswer: function(event) {
     if(event.target.value === this.state.answer) {
        this.setState({
            score: this.state.score + 1
        })
        this.serverRequest;
     }
  },

 componentDidMount: function() {
     this.serverRequest = $.get('http://jservice.io/api/random', function(data){
        var response = data[0];

        this.setState({
            question: response.question,
            answer: response.answer
        })
    }.bind(this));
 },

  render: function() {
      return (
          <div>
              <p>{this.state.question}</p>
              <input type='text' onChange={this.checkAnswer}/>
              <p>{this.state.score}</p>
          </div>
      )
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

I moved the `get` request into another method and call it in `theComponentDidMount` method.

```
getData: function() { 
    $.get('http://jservice.io/api/random', function(data){
        var response = data[0];
        console.log(response)

        this.setState({
            question: response.question,
            answer: response.answer
        })
    }.bind(this));
},

componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = this.getData()
},
```